# how to git push at server

Tags: git, git-push

In server I created repository.
In home computer I pulled.
Now I made my changes and they are working,
I need to push to server. Git refused to push.
How can I update files in the server?

```
$ git push
To ssh://erkin@mornehir.com/~/erkin
 ! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://erkin@mornehir.com/~/erkin'
 To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
 Merge the remote changes before pushing again.
 See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Did you create a bare repository? Post some details, what error message do you get?

Comment: git can refuse to push for various reasons. The output of the `git push` command would help a lot in figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: Saying "Git refused to push" ascribes this inanimate piece of software a degree of free agency and ill will bordering on the malevolent. Either your computer is possessed, or it said something other than "NO! I wont!" when you tried to do it. If the latter, knowing what it said is our only chance to help you.

Comment: $git push
To ssh://erkin@mornehir.com/~/erkin
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://erkin@mornehir.com/~/erkin'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.


is that means if I merge than push, it will accept? If it will than I'm the devil, but if git wont like my merge to accept former you wrote is valid.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the remote set up if you cloned from the home repo. So in your home repo you would:

```
git remote add origin <url/file path to your other repo>
```

now you should be able to push with:

```
git push -u origin master
```

the -u will make sure you can push later with just

```
git push
```

If you cloned and did not make a bare repo, do it again and this time include the bare option.

```
git clone --bare <file path or url to your home repo>
```

This will ensure that you can push without warnings. A non-bare repo will have a working directory and will not like having that changed by outside forces.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

That error essentially means that the history in your local repository doesn't contain that in the remote repository.  Try:

```
 git pull
```

... and then try pushing again.